# Compass Transform Mixin

Tags: css, sass, transform, compass-sass

I have the following CSS:

```
.progress-bar {
  transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1) skew(-50deg) translate(2px);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1) skew(-50deg) translate(2px);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1) skew(-50deg) translate(2px);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1) skew(-50deg) translate(2px);
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1) skew(-50deg) translate(2px);
}
```

...and would like to refactor this with the [Compass Transform](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/transform/) mixin.

There are no examples in the documentation, so I tried this as a shot in the dark:

```
.progress-bar {
  @include transform (0deg, 1, -50deg, 2px);
}
```

...and get this error:

```
Syntax error: Mixin transform takes 2 arguments but 4 were passed.
```

Is there a way to do this with Compass Transform?

Comment: Shouldn't the values be a space-seperated list? Like `@include transform (0deg 1 -50deg 2px);`?

Comment: Is such syntax supported?

Comment: @jayarjo Oh, I believe my provided version wouldn't work without the real values such as `rotate(0deg)` as in your answer, right?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You have to specify what transforms to use, separated by spaces. eg:

```
@include transform(rotate(-135deg) skew(-10deg, -10deg));
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe it should be space separated list of transforms rather than comma-separated.

```
.progress-bar {
  @include transform (rotate(0deg) scale(1) skew(-50deg) translate(2px));
}
```